# Как при помощи ExecutorService запустить несколько потоков одновременно?

Tags: java, многопоточность, execute

Помогите разобраться, когда я создаю:

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Потом

```
final Future<?> submit1 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
final Future<?> submit2 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
final Future<?> submit3 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
```

И вот тут появляется моя проблема. Если я начну вызывать у них метод `get()` то каждый будет ждать окончания предыдущего, а мне надо что-бы они одновременно работали.

```
/**
 * Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then
 * retrieves its result.
 *
```

То есть если я все правильно понимаю то если я начну вызывать:

```
submit1.get();
submit2.get();
submit3.get();
```

То второй не запустится пока не отработает первый и так далее... А как мне запустить их одновременно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поток начинает работу после вызова метода `submit`:

```
final Future<?> submit1 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
//Начал работу первый поток

final Future<?> submit2 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
//Начал работу второй поток

final Future<?> submit3 = service.submit(new Callable(...Что-то там...));
//Начал работу третий поток поток
```

Вызов `get` возвращает вам результат выполнения. То есть в случае с `Callable` вам вернется то, что возвращает метод `call`. В этом и есть суть `Future`, после вызова `submit` вы получаете объект `Future`, который в будущем вам что-то вернет.

Убедиться вы можете использовав, например, отладочный вывод внутри каждого `Callable`, а также между вызовами `submit` и `get`

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вы не правильно поняли. Запускаются они одновременно.
`get()` ожидает возврата результата запущенного таска, соответственно, если у вас `submit1.get()` будет работать 10 сек, а остальные по 1 сек, `submit1.get()` вернет управление через 10 сек, а остальные моментально, т.к. потоки уже отработают задачу.
Если вы хотите запускать все задачи асинхронно, то либо не делайте `get()` либо используйте метод `thenAccept` класса `CompletableFuture`, который вызовется после окончания работы задачи. Правда это допустимо, если у вас 8-я ява.

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете их праллельно, а вот результат получаете последовательно. Поэтому вам и кажется, что они выполняются в один поток.